# Why is method in class manipulating a __init__ variable

Tags: python, class

I have this class `Record`

```
class Record():
    def __init__(self, record):
        self.state_abbreviations = {'AL': 'Alabama'}
        self.raw_record = record
        self.is_valid = self.validate_record(self.raw_record)
        self.formatted_record = self.format_record(self.raw_record)


    def validate_record(self, record):
        if (record.get('provider_first_name') is None and 
            record.get('provider_last_name_legal_name') is None):
            return False
        return True

    def format_record(self, record):
        # swap state abbreviation for full state name
        record_state = record.get('provider_business_practice_location_address_state_name')
        full_state_name = self.state_abbreviations.get(record_state)
        record['provider_business_practice_location_address_state_name'] = full_state_name

        return record
```

when I instantiate it:

```
r = Record({'provider_first_name': 'is', 'provider_last_name_legal_name': 'fake',
            'provider_business_practice_location_address_state_name': 'AL'})
```

I would expect `r.raw_record` to give me

```
{'provider_business_practice_location_address_state_name': 'AL',
 'provider_first_name': 'is',
 'provider_last_name_legal_name': 'fake'}
```

but the output i am getting is:

```
{'provider_business_practice_location_address_state_name': 'Alabama',
 'provider_first_name': 'is',
 'provider_last_name_legal_name': 'fake'}
```

I'm confused on why the raw record is being manipulated by the `format_record` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary you're passing to the `Record` constructor is being referenced by `self.raw_record`, which is in turn passed to the `format_record` method and modified there. In all those parts you're manipulating the *same* object, that's why you see the changes in `raw_record`.

If you want to avoid this, you could make a copy of the dictionary somewhere. For example, in your constructor:

```
self.formatted_record = self.format_record(self.raw_record.copy())
```

Comment: oh cool thanks.  is there be a more pythonic way to go about what i am doing from a higher level?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking but the code doesn't look bad to me, of course that depends on what you're doing. If you need additional help, consider creating a different question to avoid having a long discussion in the comments